# NDK library not found, Android appears to omit app's library paths

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm working on an app that includes native libraries through NDK. The app builds successfully but fails on launch. I get the following message in the logcat:

```
01-14 09:05:53.658: E/AndroidRuntime(18625): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library srec_jni not found; tried [/vendor/lib/libsrec_jni.so, /system/lib/libsrec_jni.so]
```

If I examine the APK, I see there is a lib folder which contains the library that failed to load. The Java code has the usual lines of

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("srec_jni");
}
```

to load the library.

To rule out any glitches in my toolchain, I tried to build the `HelloJni` sample. It runs fine and tells me it was compiled with `armeabi-v7a`. I therefore added an `Application.mk` to my app with the following content:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 x86_64
```

According to the comments in `HelloJni.java` (from NDK samples), the package manager should place the library in `/data/data/<appname>/lib/` when installing the APK. On my device (Cyanogenmod 12), I find the lib in `/data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/lib/arm/libhello-jni.so`.

For my app, the libraries also get installed in the corresponding directory. Still AndroidRuntime isn't picking them up. The error message indicates it isn't even looking in the path where they reside. What's wrong here?

**EDIT:** Poking around a bit, I renamed `/data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/lib/arm/libhello-jni.so` and restarted the app. As expected, it crashes instantly, but the error message is slightly different:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(21670): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.hellojni-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libhello-jni.so"
```

If I rename the library of my own app, nothing changes – I still get the same error as before. It looks as if different mechanisms are involved to load the library, but I have no idea how to influence that in any way.